# Extract all Links in Table with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

```html
<td style="text-align: center;"><a title="Some title" href="https://www.blabla.com">Testing</a></td>
```

I'm trying to use `BeautifulSoup` to get all the `href` of `a` tags which are a child of a `td` tag.

I can run

```
urls = [x for x in soup.findAll("td")]
```

to obtain all the `td` tags and then loop through them manually to see if they contain an `a` tag and if so extract the `href`, but is there a cleaner way of doing this in one line?

Comment: I suppose you need something like that `links = [link['href'] for link in td.findAll('a') for td in soup.findAll('td')]`

Comment: Try this `urls = [x['href'] for x in soup.select("td>a")]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the [`:has()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) CSS Selector to select all `td`  tags that have an   `<a>` tag.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<td style="text-align: center;"><a title="Some title" href="https://www.blabla.com">Testing</a></td>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
print([tag.find("a")["href"] for tag in soup.select("td:has(a)")])
```

Output:

```
['https://www.blabla.com']
```